# Jenkins conditional project

Tags: jenkins

The projects concerned in my linked solution are the initialise database, import database and export database.
If the initialisation succeeds then 'export' should be called. If it fails then 'import' should be called.

```
      dbinit
      /     \
export       import
```

Logically this is simple enough; however, due to my lack of Jenkins experience, it's causing considerable grief.

I've looked at the following plugins:

**Conditional BuildStep** - this basically adds an 'if' statement to the build. I investigated this with the idea that the export/import projects can be collaborated into one project, using the condition to decide which course of action to take.  This could work if I was able to check the condition of the upstream build (success or failure)

**Post Build Task** - executes a shell script based on the log output. This would go in the dbinit project. The problem with this is that I would like import/export jobs to be separated from dbinit. This would work IF I could call another job from the shell

**Parameterized Trigger** - This could be perfect. This would basically solve the problem by deciding which job to run based on the status of that build. However, at the time of writing, this plugin does not perform correctly with Jenkins version 1.481 or above. This problem was raised a month ago (see [error link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15130), dated the 12th Sep 2012) and has still not been fixed, therefore I am still looking for another solution.

Can anyone tell me how to overcome the identified problems with any of these plugins?
Or is there another route that I've overlooked?

Many Thanks,

Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case jenkins 1.481 or later doesn't give you anything you need, and Parametrized Trigger works, then simply use 1.480, and wait 'till problem gets fixed (it is sure to get fixed, that's so popular plugin).

Comment: Actually checking the bug report link in the question, it may have gotten fixed yesterday :)

Comment: Thanks, I may have asked this question too soon, it seems that - as you predicted - the bug with Parameterized Trigger has been fixed in version 2.16, and will be available on the update centre shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Build Result Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) help you?

> With the BuildResultPlugin, you configure jobB to monitor jobA build result. A build is scheduled if there is a new build result matches your criteria (unstable, failure, ...)